# How to tell Seaborn/Matplotlib to show 'what you are given' on the X axis and do not assume I want the ticks to be evenly spaced numerically

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe with one column that has YYYYMM data as a float, and a second column has summaraized data for the month.

[image]

I have tried to create another dataframe column but it was never going to work as the intended output is not a date.

```
pd.to_datetime(mthly_PL_withDate_df['YearMth'].astype(str), format='%Y%m')
```

So when I plot, sns/mpl creates X axis ticks that are numerically evenly spaced when my data 'YearMth' is not. How do I tell sns/mpl to "just show what you are given and don't try to 'niceify' it".
I would have thought "showing what your are given without the introduction of assumptions" would be the default.

```
with sns.axes_style('whitegrid'):
g = sns.relplot(x='YearMth', y='PL', data=mthly_PL_withDate_df, height=5, aspect=1.5)
```

[image]

Comment: The assumption is of course that you want a linear scale and that you want to be able to assess the scale via labels. Without such assumption you would get 1000 ticklabels if plotting 1000 datapoints - which nobody wants. Concerning your problem, you indeed need to convert your data to dates first.

Comment: Thank you Mr. O. Wilde and I cannot disagree with your statement but nevertheless this nobody still wants to know if it is possible to perform what is written in the Subject of this question.

Comment: Why am I persisting with wanting to know the answer to the question? Well I just know that in the future with a probability = 1 that I will want a quick-down-n-dirty-peak at a plot without having to figure out a way to wrangle the data to make sns/mpl happy. In other words "I need to know now and not after hunting the net for the correct answer". If I need the plot to be 'correct' then sure I am happy to hunt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a float on the x-axis. It is normal for seaborn to assume that the data is numerical instead of categorical.

If you want to keep the dates as floats (strings are more correct in this case btw), you can easily fix that by setting the x_ticks property and passing your `YearMth` column to it as `ax.set_xticks([0,2,4,6])`.

This property, however, is not managed by seaborn, but instead by the underlying `matplotlib.pyplot` package. Thus you will need to modify your code a bit to expose the `subplot` object and later pass it to seaborn.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = [(10, 1), (11, 2), (12, 3), (1000, 4)]
data = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=data, columns=['x', 'y'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (12,6))
ax.set_title("Plot with controlled ticks")
ax.set_ylabel("Mode data")
ax.set_xlabel("X values with good ticks")
ax.set_xticks(range(0,len(data['x'])))
ax.set_xticklabels(list(data['x']), rotation=45)


rel_plot = sns.relplot(ax=ax, data=data, height=5, aspect=1.5)
```

The code above will give you the expected result: 
[image]

Overall, subplots give you very fine control over the visualization of the displayed data (you can look up the full `subplot` api [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html)).

Comment: Thank you so much @Simas Joneliunas. I 'cheated' :) and created a new string column. `mthly_PL_withDate_df['YYYYMM'] = mthly_PL_withDate_df['YearMth'].astype(int).astype(str)`

Comment: That is the preferred way to go. I simply provided this answer as a `long way around` solution~

Comment: Your solution is great as I can use it one day to force axes to display 'unusual' values. Thanks again @Simas Joneliunas. But if you do have a moment perhaps you could cast your eye over a few comments that I made to a comment under the body of my post.

Comment: if I understood your question correctly - axis manipulation is one of the quick and dirty ways of looking into the data. You just need to dump the "x" column from the df into the chart and you are done. Alternatively, I'd probably preprocess the data a little bit so that the data would fir a linear'ish scale (i.e. use T+n months instead of date floats). Unfortunately, if you  are working with semi-structured data, you can hardly escape data cleaning.